# How to customize keyboard shortcuts in Jupyter Lab to run current line or selected text?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I happen to use "Run Selected Text or Current Line in Console" command a lot under the "Run" menu in JupyterLab. How can we configure a custom keyboard shortcut in JupterLab/Jupyter notebook for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**For JupyterLab**

Go to `Settings` and choose `Advanced Settings editor`. Under the `Keyboard shortcuts` tab, copy the entire `System Defaults` content to `User Preferences` column and find section containing:

```
"command": "notebook:run-in-console",
      "keys": [
        ""
      ],
```

Add the key combination you wish and save, e.g:

```
"keys": [
  "F12"
],
```

Answer (score 3):

Once JupterLab is open click the Settings dropdown menu. Select Advanced Settings Editor.
Select Keyboard Shortcuts.
You’ll see a dictionary for each option in the System Defaults panel. There are a bunch of options, so you might want to Command + F (Ctrl + F on Windows) to find the one you want. Copy the code of the one you want to override.
Here’s the section for restart-and-run-all.

```
{"shortcuts": 
    [
        {
            "command": "runmenu:restart-and-run-all",
            "keys": [
                "Ctrl Shift R"
            ],
            "selector": "[data-jp-code-runner]"
        }
    ]
}
```

I suggest making sure you aren’t overriding another JupyterLab keyboard shortcut by searching the System Defaults Panel for your new key combination.
And there you have it. Press Command + S (Ctrl + S on Windows) to save, open a notebook file, and try out your new keyboard shortcut!

[Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-customize-jupyterlab-keyboard-shortcuts-72321f73753d#:%7E:text=Select%20Advanced%20Settings%20Editor.,find%20the%20one%20you%20want.)

Comment: What does selector mean?

Comment: regarding the question about "selector". (AFAIK) This works in the same way as CSS does. "body" means the html `<body>` tag and ".something" means some html tag with a "something" class.