# JupyterLab key bindings on Mac: customize moveWordLeft/moveWordRight/copy/paste

Tags: jupyter, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, jupyter-lab, key-bindings

I have moved from Linux to Mac and successfully mapped Ctrl+Left/Right to moveWordLeft/Right (and so for copy/paste/cut/undo/redo).

For help with this see https://superuser.com/questions/657724/how-to-remap-ctrlarrow-keys-to-move-word-to-word-for-mac
and
https://superuser.com/questions/28078/remap-copy-and-paste-shortcuts-on-a-mac
and
[https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24609/remapping-keyboard-shortcuts-in-chrome-and-firefox#:~:text=However%2C%20there%20is%20a%20way,from%20the%20list%20of%20Apps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24609/remapping-keyboard-shortcuts-in-chrome-and-firefox#:%7E:text=However%2C%20there%20is%20a%20way,from%20the%20list%20of%20Apps).

What I have not been able to do is make these mappings propagate to JupyterLab running in Chrome or Firefox (note that both browsers in general respect the new system-wide key bindings, but JupyterLab is among a small subset of apps/pages/extensions that only recognize key remappings specified WITHIN that specific app/page/extension).

I have found a number of instructions on how to edit JupyterLab key bindings, but none of them pertaining to actual in-cell (edit mode) navigation keys:
[How to customize keyboard shortcuts in Jupyter Lab to run current line or selected text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310510/how-to-customize-keyboard-shortcuts-in-jupyter-lab-to-run-current-line-or-select)
https://towardsdatascience.com/customizing-jupyter-lab-shortcuts-6857492647d2
https://nocomplexity.com/documents/jupyterlab/keyboardshortcuts.html
https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/keyboard_shortcut_editor/README.html
[Jupyter lab shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280261/jupyter-lab-shortcuts)
[In Jupyter Lab, execute editor code in Python console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648286/in-jupyter-lab-execute-editor-code-in-python-console)
[Jupyter lab shortcut modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66940914/jupyter-lab-shortcut-modification)

In the default options from the JupyterLab settings GUI, NONE of the commands pertain to useful bindings in edit mode (e.g., the only options they give for changing copy/paste shortcuts are in the edit-menu and text-editor section, meaning they only apply to stuff outside the actual code cells), and even when I toggle these to test it out the changes don't stick.

Does anyone have specific instructions for mapping new keys to moveWordLeft/moveWordRight in the actual in-cell edit mode of JupyterLab? If I can get those I'm sure I can figure out the copy/paste and other more common shortcuts from there.